# RestTemplate does not follow redirects even when GET is used

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-oauth2

I am using the RestTemplate class to get to some page, which will require redirect ( redirect to oauth 2 provider, but that probably doesnt matter ).

I am doing:

```
ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = oAuth2RestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class, Collections.emptyMap());
```

with standard `OAuth2RestTemplate`, I haven't done any custom creation of this bean, so it is just injected from Spring.

As a response I get a `ResponseEntity` with `location` header and 302 status, but it is not followed. Judging by many other sources RestTemplate should follow redirects by default if all I do is `GET` - similar issue here: [Follow 302 redirect using Spring restTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418583/follow-302-redirect-using-spring-resttemplate)

This is not a case, no redirect happens, am I missing something? Do I have to manually grab this `location`  and redirect to it manually?

**update:**

OK, OAuth2RestTemplate is using OAuth2AccessTokenSupport as a request factory. This class configures factory to **NOT** follow redirects. Too bad it is so hard to find.

But using `= new RestTemplate()` doesnt help either ( note new keyword, if you are going to autowire it, then Spring will autowire oauth2RestTemplate ).

Comment: Please post your update as answer and accept it. It may save somebody's time someday.

Comment: Whatever RestTemplate you use, use request factory with Apache HTTP Client. It is much more capable then default request factory:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024709/spring-resttemplate-follow-redirect-with-cookie/37054521#37054521