# Get Cookie By name after a restTemplate call

Tags: java, httprequest, resttemplate

I'm sending a request ro a service that set a cookie in the response :

```
HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange
                (myUrl,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new HttpEntity<>(headers),
                        String.class);
```

I found that I can extract the cookie using this line of code :

```
String set_cookie = response.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
```

However this returns: name_of_cookie=value_of_cookie

I know that I can make a String processing to extract the value of the cookie by name, but I want to find a better solution in the manner of :

```
response.getHeaders().getCookieValueByName(cookie_name)
```

The getCookieValueByName function do not exsist. Is there a function that does what I want to do ?

Comment: let's try to use java.net.HttpCookie.parse(set_cookie) which returns List<HttpCookie>

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853321/resttemplate-client-with-cookies