# How to get Response Header information from Spring RestTemplate GET request

Tags: java, json, spring, get, resttemplate

I am triggering a `GET` request and getting the `JSON` data successfully via Spring `RestTemplate`. I also want to get the `Response Header` information but I am not sure how to get it.

```
private String getAPIKeySpring() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = baseURL+"/users/apikey";
        Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        vars.put("X-Auth-User", apiUser);
        JsonVO jsonVO =  restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonVO.class, vars);
        System.out.println(jsonVO);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005709/how-do-i-read-the-response-header-from-resttemplate

Comment: @ashosborne1 That is for post request, I am not having request object to pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ResponseEntity<JsonVO> responseEntity =  restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonVO.class, vars);
JsonVO jsonVO = responseEntity.getBody();
HttpHeaders headers = responseEntity.getHeaders(); //<-- your headers
```