# Spring restTemplate execute( ) POST large files and obtain a response

Tags: java, spring, rest, stream, resttemplate

This took me quite a while to work out so I wanted to share it.  Most information came from SO and I wanted to consolidate into this one place.

My requirements are to upload files using a RESTFul POST.  Due to possibly large files I wanted to stream the files. I obviously want to be able to read the response.

I planned to use Jersey as the REST Server and Spring's RestTemplate as the client (and for testing).

The problem I faced was streaming POSTs and receiving a response.  How can I do that?  (Rhetorical question - I answer this!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using SpringBoot `1.2.4.RELEASE` with Jersey being pulled in by:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
```

I created the project with the brilliant Spring Starter Project (`Spring Tool Suite > New` or you can do through a website I believe and no doubt IntelliJ has this capability also).  And chose 'Jersey (JAX-RS)' option.  In the gradle `build.gradle` I also added the dependency:

```
compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
```

I wrote this server side code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import org.me.fileStore.service.FileStoreService;

@RestController
@Path("/filestore")
public class FileStoreRestService {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileStoreRestService.class);

    @Autowired
    private FileStoreService fileStoreService;


    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response Upload(InputStream stream) throws IOException, URISyntaxException { //
        String location = fileStoreService.upload(stream);  // relative path
        URI loc = new URI(location);
        Response response = Response.created(loc).build();
        System.out.println("POST - response: " + response + ", :" + response.getHeaders());
        return response;
    }
```

Where i had most troubles was in getting a Response with a location.

Firstly I had to handle streaming large files.  I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/15785322/1019307 as you can see in the test below.  I was NOT obtaining a Response no matter what I tried with the `HttpMessageConverterExtractor` as per that post:

```
final HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String> responseExtractor =
new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String>(String.class, restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
```

After finding https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006147/1019307 I wrote:

```
private static class ResponseFromHeadersExtractor implements ResponseExtractor<ClientHttpResponse> {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        System.out.println("StringFromHeadersExtractor - response headers: " + response.getHeaders());
        return response;
    }
}
```

This gave me this test:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback;
import org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = FileStoreApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:9000")
public class FileStoreRestServiceTest {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileStoreRestServiceTest.class);
    protected final Log logger2 = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    String base = "http://localhost:9000/filestore";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

@Test
public void testMyMethodExecute() throws IOException {
    String content = "This is file contents\nWith another line.\n";
    Path theTestFilePath = TestingUtils.getTempPath(content);
    InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(theTestFilePath);

    String url = base + "/upload";
    final RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRequest(final ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, request.getBody());
        }
    };
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    ClientHttpResponse response = restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback,
            new ResponseFromHeadersExtractor());
    URI location = response.getHeaders().getLocation();
    System.out.println("Location: " + location);
    Assert.assertNotNull(location);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(0, location.getPath().length());

}

private static class ResponseFromHeadersExtractor implements ResponseExtractor<ClientHttpResponse> {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        System.out.println("StringFromHeadersExtractor - response headers: " + response.getHeaders());
        return response;
    }
}
```

I need to refactor much in that test out into some services.

Answer (score 7):

It's unnecessary to go through all these hoops with a `RequestCallback`. Simply use a [`PathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/PathResource.html).

```
PathResource pathResource = new PathResource(theTestFilePath);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(pathResource), String.class);
```

Spring will use a [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html) to serialize the file identified by the given `Path` to the request body. Internally, the Spring 4.x implementation uses a buffer size of 4096 bytes (which is also what `IOUtils#copy(..)` uses).

Obviously, you can provide the response type you want. The example above expects the response body as a `String`. With a `ResponseEntity`, you can access all the response headers with

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();
```

Comment: If that works (i'll test shortly) then great!  `RestTemplate.exchange()` was much better for auto-handling the Response without the need for `ResponseFromHeadersExtractor` (Which I just noticed I forgot to add - so will edit my answer now).  So yes, this seems a much better solution.  

I did alot of searching and did not find this.  The power of throwing it out there!

Comment: I can't get that to work.  I get a 404 as it doesn't seem to match a PathResource.  I've played with this but can't get it going.  Any suggestions?  See my implementation in my answer (swap PathResource inplace of InputStream).

Comment: @HankCa A 404 has nothing to do with the entity you send in the body. Your URL is bad. Turn on debug logs on your server and check what you're actually requesting.

Comment: My experience has been that if the signature doesn't match then an endpoint isn't matched and hence a 404.  For example I had the same result when i had `FileInputStream` instead of `InputStream`.  I just tried that again and that is indeed the case.  Though I accept your advice of turning on logging.  I will come back to that.

Comment: @HankCa I don't know how Jersey does it, but assuming you're using a parameter type that is supported, whether by default or through a custom provider, it should not affect the handler mappings. A 404 is a client error. You're sending the request to a URL that your server does not have a handler for. If what you are describing is actually happening, then I would assume Jersey is doing something wrong.

Comment: So what you expect to happen if its just a body parameter difference is just not handle the data well (throw an exception there to give a 500 error).  Sounds reasonable.  Though yes it does seem like Jersey is doing something different.  Thanks for your feedback.